# extended visual state manager not works in wp8.1 app on windows 10 mobile for phones

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1, visualstatemanager, windows-10

I have an app which doesn't work properly on w10m. 
Yes, I now about non-release state of w10m, but the app in the store and users are complaining.

Here is the hierarchy of the UI (like in the real project):

```
Hub
  HubSection
    DataTemplate
      Grid
        ExtendedVSM
        VSM
        Content
```

1. How I can fix the ExtendedVisualStateManager on w10m?
2. Or, maybe, how I can detect w10m OS version in the app and show to user some notice?

Source code https://github.com/bondarenkod/extended-visual-state-manager-w10m-bug

Blue rectangle in the center of the screen - it's action button for change VSM state.

***Left** image it's correct behavior (on wp81), **right** - incorrect (w10m)*
[image: correct (wp81)] [image: incorrect (w10m)]

Comment: Please log app-compat issues via the Windows Feedback app in Windows 10.

Comment: I logged this as an issue but in the future please make sure you do it :-)